# Python: Input as list?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I am getting input in the form of:

```
4 11111
```

I am using `a,b = map(int,raw_input().split())` to store 4 in a and 11111 in b. 
But I want b to be a list, how am I supposed to do that ?

Comment: You want `b` to be a list of what? `[11111]`, `[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]`? And what input are you expecting in general?

Comment: I want b to be [1, 1, 1, 1, 1] so that I can add all the values in b .

Answer (score 4):

You can just use `list` :

```
>>> list('11111')
['1', '1', '1', '1', '1']
```

But in that case you can not use [`map`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) function because it just apply one function on its iterable argument and in your code it convert the whole of `'11111'` to integer so you have tow way :

1. create `b` as a list of string ones :

> ```
> inp=raw_input().split()
> a,b = int(inp[0]),list(inp[1])
> ```

2. if you want a list of integer 1's use `map` :

> ```
> >>> map(int,'11111')
> [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
> ```

Comment: But I need the 1`s in list to be integers

Comment: Always provide links to the docs. https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map

Answer (score 3):

```
a, b = map(int, raw_input().strip().split())
```

char list:

```
l = list(str(b))
```

int list:

```
l = [int(i) for i in str(b)]
```

Comment: there is no need to strip, you also end up with strings so why cast to int and then turn them back into strings again?

Comment: fyi, ozgur added strip()

Comment: who added the `l = list(str(b))`?

Comment: I wrote everything except strip().

Comment: `a, b = "4 11111".split();a, b = int(a), list(b)`  will be  more efficient.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this in two steps:

```
a, b = raw_input().split()
a, b = int(a), map(int, b)
print a
print b
```

Returns: 4 and [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]